# Javascript RegExp replace with negative lookahead

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to replace some value in the query string of the current page using JS. Eg: from `category=Old Value` to `category=New Value`.
To code looks like this:

```
var sNewValue = 'New Value';
sQueryString = sQueryString.replace(/category=[^&]+&?/, 'category=' + sNewValue);
```

It works fine except for values that have ampersands. Luckily all the ampersands are URL encoded, so I know I should discard the **amp;** before the **&**. I think I should use lookaheads, but I don't know how. I tried this regular expression, but with no luck: `/category=[^&(?!amp;)]+&?/`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are ampersands being encoded as &amp; instead of %26? Or am I reading your question wrong?

If that's the way it needs to be, it might be easier for you to deal with this query string if you break it into name/value pairs first.

```
var pairStrings = sQueryString.split(/&(?!amp;)/gi);
```

Then you can work with each value without worrying if it contains an encoded & or not.

Comment: Thanks, for your answer. It seems like the easiest solution for me was to first replace **&amp;** with **%26**. And then do my processing.

Answer (score 1):

You don’t need to specify a following `&` at all:

```
var sNewValue = 'New Value';
sQueryString = sQueryString.replace(/(^|&)category=[^&]*/, '$1category=' + encodeURIComponent(sNewValue));
```

Because `[^&]` does already match any character except `&`. Furthermore, if *category* is the last parameter, there even is no following `&`.

Comment: This doesn't work if value has an encoded &amp; which is what I think he was trying to address.

Comment: @adam0101: URIs don’t know anything about HTML character references because URIs are not HTML. The `&` separates the name/value pairs (see http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1). That means `category=New&amp;Value&cat2=blah` results in three name/value pairs: *category* having `New`, *amp;Value* with no value, and *cat2* having `blah`.

Comment: That may be, but if the query string he is working with has ampersands encoded as &amp; instead of %26 then he will need code that can deal with that or else fix how the query string is being created, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I actually found what you need.

```
var sNewValue = 'category=New Value&';
sQueryString = sQueryString.replace(/category=([^&]|&amp;)*&/, sNewValue)
```

Comment: If the value was 'category=New&amp;Value&cat2=blah' this would capture 'category=New&' instead of 'category=New&amp;Value&' which is what I think he wants.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
var sNewValue = 'New Value';
sQueryString = sQueryString.replace(/\bcategory=[^&]*/, 'category=' + sNewValue);
```

This will replace even if category is preceded by `?` as in `/foo.php?category=bar`

Answer (score 0):

You don't get lookbehind in JavaScript regular expressions. You *do* get lookahead, but it is unreliable in IE, so best avoided unless you really know what you're doing.

```
[^&(?!amp;)]+&
```

yeah, this doesn't really make any sense. You can't use lookahead in a `[]` character group: what you're saying here is match characters that aren't `&`, `(`, `?`, `!` , `a`, `m`, `p`, `;`, or `)`.

However you should not see `&amp;` anyway: you should be working on a plain, unencoded query string, eg. as fetched from `location.search`. (If you are hacking at HTML markup in a string with regex you've got much, much bigger problems.)

If you *are* getting the query string from `location.search`, you'll have a `?` on the front if there's any query. So you can match the beginning with either `&` or `?`, and do your regex match on:

```
location.search.replace(
    /([?&;]category=)[^&;]+/,
    '$1'+encodeURIComponent(sNewValue)
);
```

note I have also included `;` as a possible separator as per HTML4 section B.2.2, and used `encodeURIComponent` so that invalid characters like spaces and special characters like `&` itself get properly URL-encoded. Also the character `$`, which otherwise has special meaning in a regexp replacement string.

This is still quite messy, and doesn't cope with URL-encoded parameter names (ie `c%61tegory` is a valid alternative way of saying `category`) or multiple parameters with the same name. If you want to be more robust about it you could dump the regexps and do full query string parsing/reconstruction. See the functions from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3644059/javascript-regex-remove-a-querystring-variable-if-present/3644307#3644307) and do:

```
var lookup= queryToLookup(location.search);
lookup['category']= ['New value'];
var query= lookupToQuery(lookup);
```

Answer (score 0):

`/(\bcategory=)(([^&]|&amp\;)*)/`

This includes the many different scenarios:

```
   var s1 = 'http://www.foobar.com/?category=old&foo=bar';
   var s2 = 'http://www.foobar.com/?category=old';
   var s3 = 'http://www.foobar.com/?foo=bar&category=old';
   var s4 = 'http://www.foobar.com/?foo=bar&category=old&amp;value';
   var s5 = 'http://www.foobar.com/?foo=bar&category=old&amp;value&bar=foo';

   var n  = 'NewVal';

   console.log( s1.replace(/(\bcategory=)(([^&]|&amp\;)*)/, "$1" + n) );
   console.log( s2.replace(/(\bcategory=)(([^&]|&amp\;)*)/, "$1" + n) );
   console.log( s3.replace(/(\bcategory=)(([^&]|&amp\;)*)/, "$1" + n) );
   console.log( s4.replace(/(\bcategory=)(([^&]|&amp\;)*)/, "$1" + n) );
   console.log( s5.replace(/(\bcategory=)(([^&]|&amp\;)*)/, "$1" + n) );

   // s1 output: http://www.foobar.com/?category=NewVal&foo=bar
   // s2 output: http://www.foobar.com/?category=NewVal
   // s3 output: http://www.foobar.com/?foo=bar&category=NewVal
   // s4 output: http://www.foobar.com/?foo=bar&category=NewVal
   // s5 output: http://www.foobar.com/?foo=bar&category=NewVal&bar=foo
```

You may want to add a global switch.