# Remove all spaces and tabs from html() variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a hidden div on my page and I just want to get the HTML structure.

```
<div class="html-to-store visuallyhidden">
    <span class="item">
        <p>Test</p>
        <p>Another Test</p>
    </span>
    <span class="item">
        <p>Second Test</p>
        <p>Dadada</p>
    </span>
</div>
```

and my JavaScript:

```
var storeThis = $('.html-to-store').html();
```

Now, this is good, but I want to be able to get all the HTML tags in one single line.

Here's [what I'm currently getting](http://jsfiddle.net/t8zRJ/):

```
<span class="item">
    <p>Test</p>
    <p>Another Test</p>
</span>
<span class="item">
    <p>Second Test</p>
    <p>Dadada</p>
</span>
```

What I'd like is the following:

```
<span class="item"><p>Test</p><p>Another Test</p></span><span class="item"><p>Second Test</p><p>Dadada</p></span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Tiny jQuery plugin for this purpose:**

```
(function( $ ){
    $.fn.getUnformattedText = function () {
        return $.trim($(this).html()
                  .split(/\>[\n\t\s]*\</g).join('><')
                  .split(/[\n\t]*/gm).join(''));
    }
})( jQuery );
```

**Usage:**

```
$('.html-to-store').getUnformattedText();
```

**Fiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/marionebl/t8zRJ/10/

Comment: This is not good if you have multiple class names. Removes the space between the clases

Comment: Updated to prevent borked classes and text nodes.

Comment: Cool, thanks. That is a good alternative to the accepted answer and I would take this if I'd care about the looks of my code, but for now I just want the damn thing to work! Thanks alot for helping out.

Comment: Since this is more clean and the previous answer was not removing all white space I decided to add your answer as correct. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

How about some crude regex?  Split and join, removing the whitespace.

[Javascript RegExp replace with negative lookahead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3761307/javascript-regexp-replace-with-negative-lookahead)

```
var storeThis = $('.html-to-store').html().split(/>[\s]*</g).join('><');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t8zRJ/3/

Comment: Works! :D I wish I understood regualr expressions

Comment: No one really understands them.  :)

Comment: This does not deal with newlines and whitespace before / after the html string.

Comment: @marionebl is correct, but I think it leads in the right direction.

Comment: the_html..split(/>[\s]*</g).join('><').trim(), we can add .trim() as well

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to remove all the blank text nodes, so try

```
$(function () {
    $('.html-to-store').contents().contents().addBack().filter(function () {
        return this.nodeType == 3 && $.trim(this.nodeValye) == ''
    }).remove();

    var storeThis = $('.html-to-store').html();

    $('textarea').val(storeThis);

});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/LfSzW/)

If you don't want to modify the html structure in the dom then use clone like [in here](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/LfSzW/2/)

Comment: This is really good, but unfortunately, work only for 3 level deep. I don't really know how deep my content will go after a while